# a onde eu encontro esses ícones

Tags: html, css

Estou precisando mudar esses ícones no site... como eu faço ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
  $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 900, function(){
   
        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".slideanim").each(function(){
      var pos = $(this).offset().top;

      var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (pos < winTop + 600) {
          $(this).addClass("slide");
        }
    });
  });
})
```

```css
body {
    font: 400 15px Lato, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color:darkturquoise;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #303030;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1.375em;
    color: #303030;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }  
  .jumbotron {
    background-color: #33ccff;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 100px 25px;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  }
  .container-fluid {
    padding: 60px 50px;
      color: black;
  }
  .bg-grey {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
  }
  .logo-small {
    color: RED;
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  .logo {
    color: #f4511e;
    font-size: 200px;
  }
  .thumbnail {
    padding: 0 0 15px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left {
    background-image: none;
    color: #1176BC;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li {
    border-color: #1176BC;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li.active {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .item h4 {
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1.375em;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 70px 0;
  }
  .item span {
    font-style: normal;
  }
  .panel {
    border: 1px solid #33ccff; 
    border-radius:0 !important;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  }
  .panel:hover {
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
  }
  .panel-footer .btn:hover {
    border: 1px solid #1176BC;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    color: #1176BC;
  }
  .panel-heading {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #33ccff !important;
    padding: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  }
  .panel-footer {
    background-color:important;
  }
  .panel-footer h3 {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
  .panel-footer h4 {
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .panel-footer .btn {
    margin: 15px 0;
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #009BCE;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  }
  .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
    color: black !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #fff !important;
  }
  footer .glyphicon {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #f4511e;
  }
  .slideanim {visibility:hidden;}
  .slide {
    animation-name: slide;
    -webkit-animation-name: slide;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  @keyframes slide {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(70%);
    } 
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
    } 
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-4 {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 25px 0;
    }
    .btn-lg {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 35px;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .logo {
      font-size: 150px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Theme Made By www.w3schools.com -->
  <title>Brown Odontologia</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--- zoom desativado para o usuario -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>

<div id="services" class="container-fluid text-center">
  <h2>SERVICES</h2>
  <h4>What we offer</h4>
  <br>
  <div class="row slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off logo-small"></span>
      <h4>POWER</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart logo-small"></span>
      <h4>LOVE</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock logo-small"></span>
      <h4>JOB DONE</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="row slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf logo-small"></span>
      <h4>GREEN</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate logo-small"></span>
      <h4>CERTIFIED</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench logo-small"></span>
      <h4 style="color:#303030;">HARD WORK</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No caso você deseja mudar os ícones por outros ? acho que precisa de mais detalhes sobre a mudança

Comment: sim por outros itens ... :D

Comment: Os ícones são definidos pelas classes `glyphicon-*`, veja a [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse site está a usar [Glyphicon](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp) como imagens:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off logo-small"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart logo-small"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock logo-small"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf logo-small"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate logo-small"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench logo-small"></span>
```

Bastas mudar esses tags `<span>` por imagens `<img>` ou outra coisas que queiras.

Exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
  $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 900, function(){
   
        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".slideanim").each(function(){
      var pos = $(this).offset().top;

      var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (pos < winTop + 600) {
          $(this).addClass("slide");
        }
    });
  });
})
```

```css
body {
    font: 400 15px Lato, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color:darkturquoise;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #303030;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1.375em;
    color: #303030;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }  
  .jumbotron {
    background-color: #33ccff;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 100px 25px;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  }
  .container-fluid {
    padding: 60px 50px;
      color: black;
  }
  .bg-grey {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
  }
  .logo-small {
    color: RED;
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  .logo {
    color: #f4511e;
    font-size: 200px;
  }
  .thumbnail {
    padding: 0 0 15px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .carousel-control.right, .carousel-control.left {
    background-image: none;
    color: #1176BC;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li {
    border-color: #1176BC;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li.active {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .item h4 {
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1.375em;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 70px 0;
  }
  .item span {
    font-style: normal;
  }
  .panel {
    border: 1px solid #33ccff; 
    border-radius:0 !important;
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  }
  .panel:hover {
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
  }
  .panel-footer .btn:hover {
    border: 1px solid #1176BC;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    color: #1176BC;
  }
  .panel-heading {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #33ccff !important;
    padding: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  }
  .panel-footer {
    background-color:important;
  }
  .panel-footer h3 {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
  .panel-footer h4 {
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .panel-footer .btn {
    margin: 15px 0;
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #009BCE;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  }
  .navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
    color: black !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #fff !important;
  }
  footer .glyphicon {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #f4511e;
  }
  .slideanim {visibility:hidden;}
  .slide {
    animation-name: slide;
    -webkit-animation-name: slide;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  @keyframes slide {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(70%);
    } 
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
    } 
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-4 {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 25px 0;
    }
    .btn-lg {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 35px;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .logo {
      font-size: 150px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Theme Made By www.w3schools.com -->
  <title>Brown Odontologia</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--- zoom desativado para o usuario -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>

<div id="services" class="container-fluid text-center">
  <h2>SERVICES</h2>
  <h4>What we offer</h4>
  <br>
  <div class="row slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
      <h4>POWER</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
      <h4>LOVE</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
      <h4>JOB DONE</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="row slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
      <h4>GREEN</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
      <h4>CERTIFIED</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
      <h4 style="color:#303030;">HARD WORK</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: o man conseguir ! muito Obrigado :D

Answer (score 0):

Para mudar os ícones basta ir nas tags  `<span>` e mudar o nome do icone por outro da lista do Bootstrap.

Exemplo:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off logo-small"></span>
```

Serve para mostrar o ícone de energia (o primeiro da imagem) então para mudar para um uma carta por exemplo basta remover o nome **glyphicon glyphicon-off** e colocar **glyphicon glyphicon-envelope** em seu lugar. Ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope logo-small"></span>
```

A lista com os ícones que o Bootstrap da suporte por padrão pode ser vista nesse link:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/